# JSON-LD External Context Redirect

Tags: json, xml-parsing, json-ld

When defining external documents in a JSON-LD context there may be situations where offline processing is desired or just for speed of processing you may want to reference a local copy of those external documents.

Is there a procedure similar to using XML Catalogs for JSON-LD?

So I can consume JSON-LD that references http://www.example.com/one.jsonld as a context document but actually use  ~/myjsonld/one.jsonld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard-compliant JSON-LD processors should allow you to specify a custom "documentLoader" which you can use to do things like that.

Here's the link to the official specification defining this option: http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld-api/#the-jsonldoptions-type